# Charge a metal by applying potential

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, voltage

I don't understand why if we apply a potential to a metal it can attract electrons. An example of this is an electron gun, the anode is at a positive potential and its function is to attract the electrons to leave the gun.

[image]

This means that if we apply a positive potential to a metal it behaves like a positive charge? To calculate the charge that said plate acquired, can be calculated using the following equation?

$$V_{\mathbf E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{Q}{R^2}$$

Another question, is a metal supposed to have as many positive and negative charges, if the metal is positively charged what happens to the negative charges? Why don't they contribute to the force?

Comment: So the potential in the metal creates an electric field, but if it creates an electric field that means there are charges, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't take many. There are lots of electrons to move around.